# Rspec running very, very slowly on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am running Ruby on Rails 5.1.4 and am trying to upgrade to Ruby 2.5.1 from Ruby 2.4.4.  When I run Rspec, it is running incredibly slowly. I have used the method described [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1353) by myronmarston allows me to see what is happening.

The Rspec program appears to be progressing normally, just every step is taking a long time, for example it takes over half an hour to finish the rspec.configure block in `spec_helper`, minutes to execute a validate statement in a model. I have tried different tests and it is not any specific test code.

If I start up the rails server, the app appears to be working normally. The console appears to work normally as well, it is just rspec. I have tried `spring stop` and it makes no difference to outcome.

Any ideas on what is causing this?

Comment: It seems there could be `env` differences. Did you try to profile the specs?

Comment: What happens if you run `rspec --profile`? Is it happening also if you run a single test and not the whole suite?

Comment: It happens with one test or all tests. It takes more than two hours to finish one simple test, so It is not practicable to use rspec --profile, and I do no think it is one particular test, it appears that the entire process is running in slow motion. The rails server runs at the normal speed.